# busybox is variable a number?

Tags: regex, busybox

following script works as expected on my Ubuntu 16.04 shell:

```
Teststring="1234a5"
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $TestString =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "is not a number"
  exit 1
fi
```

On my target although, I have only busybox instead of a full blown shell and it raises following error:

```
ash: =~: unknown operand
```

How do I make it work with busybox?

Background: I have a busybox script that wants to read a number from a special file on the system, do some calculations with it and writing the result out to a different file. 
Before running into "not a number"-Errors later, I want to do a propper check bevorehand.

Comment: Do it the old-school way.. use egrep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With external tools

egrep

```
if ! echo "$Teststring" | egrep -q "$re"; then
```

or modifying re

```
re='[0-9]\+'
if ! expr "$Teststring" : "$re"; then
```

- using builtin shell expansion

in that particular case: if string is empty or contains a non digit

```
case $Teststring in
    ''|*[!0-9]*) 
    echo "is not a number"     
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: you're welcome, feel free to accept answer and vote if it helps